# How to make a div disappear on hover without it flickering when the mouse moves?

Tags: css, hover, hide, visibility, opacity

I've seen answers suggesting just `display:none` on the `:hover` css. But that makes the div flicker when the mouse is moving.

EDIT: Added [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CGFMX/)

Comment: Please post the exact html and css that is giving you this issue, and preferably put it in a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: are you okay with using jQuery?

Comment: Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/VvsG2/

Comment: Thanks Jared, I just added one too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`display:none` will take the element out of the render tree,  so it loses `:hover` state immediately, then reappears and gets `:hover` again, disappears, reappears, etc...

What **you need** is:

```css
#elem { opacity:0; filter:alpha(opacity=0); }
```

It will leave the place empty, so no flickering will appear. **([Demo](http://jsbin.com/arape4/)** *or* **[yours updated](http://jsfiddle.net/CGFMX/1/))**

Comment: All three examples (visibility, display, opacity): http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/VvsG2/4/

Answer (score 1):

Optionally with CSS3, but will only work on latest browsers (excluding IE).
Edit: Here is an example @ [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robx/jrnFj/2/) using both jquery and CSS3.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>CSS3 hover</title>
<style type="text/css">
#hover{
     width:100px;
     height:100px;
     background-color:#000000;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition:opacity 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition:opacity 0.2s ease;
}
#hover:hover{
    // Red(0-255), Blue(0-255), Green(0-255), Alpha (0-1)
    background-color:rgba(100,100,100,0); 
    opacity:0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="hover"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh yea, I didn't mention that the JS method will work across browsers, the CSS3 will not work with IE ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript to set a class (eg. invisible) on the object when hovered over. Then use css to display:none when the object has that invisible class. Since it doesn't exist anymore you will have to check mouse coordinates (or use another element mouse hover event) to remove the class and reset the invisible class.

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like this:

```
div:hover
{
  display:none;
}
```

Then there is no way for you to avoid flickering.
On :hover the element becomes invisible so it is not hovered anymore and it appears again.
As soon as it appears it is getting :hover again and ...

On :hover the element becomes invisible so it is not hovered anymore and it appears again.
As soon as it appears it is getting :hover again and ...

On :hover the element becomes invisible so it is not hovered anymore and it appears again.
As soon as it appears it is getting :hover again and ...

On :hover the element becomes invisible so it is not hovered anymore and it appears again.
As soon as it appears it is getting :hover again and ...

On :hover the element becomes invisible so it is not hovered anymore and it appears again.
As soon as it appears it is getting :hover again and ...

...
It flickers to be short.
A better option would be to use opacity, something like this:

```
div:hover
{
  opacity:0;
}
```