# How to replace content of a div with content from pseudo class on hover

Tags: html, css

```css
 body{
        font-size: 24px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        margin: 75px 0;
    }
    
    .button{
        
        padding: 1px 3px 2px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        white-space: nowrap;
        background-color: #bfbfbf;
        border-radius: 3px;
        text-decoration: none;
        max-height: 24px;
        
        }
    
    .button:hover{
       display:"none";
      
        }
    
    .button:hover:after{
        content: 'my second box';
        cursor: crosshair;
        background-color: #46a546;
  
        }
```

```html
<body>
    
     <div class="button">my first box</div>

    
</body>
```

Here's some [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fLMSd/1681/) to tinker.  I feel like I have tried every combination to make this work!  Any ideas on the types of changes I need to make to this code in order to stop the original box from just movinng over to the side?

Comment: Why don't you try `display:none;` instead of `display:"none"`?

Comment: Removing the quotes is a good start, but then I'm also seeing issues with the way the `:hover:after` is working, not sure it's meant to be used that way.

Comment: Remove the quotes and you will start to see a flicker when hovering.  See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844622/how-to-make-a-div-disappear-on-hover-without-it-flickering-when-the-mouse-moves for the reason why.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to have the content inside of `.button` be replaced with the content of your `:after` psuedo class on hover, you're going to need to introduce another element. When you hide an element, it's psuedo elements are also going to be hidden. You can do this by nesting a `span` around the content you want to hide, and hide the span instead, then "replace" the span's content with content from the parent element's pseudo element on hover - like this. (ps - you need to remove the quotes from `display: "none";` - should be `display: none;` instead)

```css
body {
  font-size: 24px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 75px 0;
}

.button span {
  padding: 1px 3px 2px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #bfbfbf;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  max-height: 24px;
  display: block;
}

.button:hover span {
  display: none;
}

.button:hover:after {
  content: 'my second box';
  cursor: crosshair;
  background-color: #46a546;
}
```

```html
<div class="button"><span>my first box</span></div>
```