# Show div on hover on same position

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to show div on mouseover, but it's flickering, how do I show/hide without any jerk and smooth with the transition?

I have tried the fade in/out using jquery as well but still blinking.

Here is the code

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
}
.row {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
}
.col {
 float: left;
 width: 25%;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
.front {
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
 background-color: #999
}
.back {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 height: 300px;
 opacity: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
 background-color: #ff0;
 z-index: 2;
 width: 100%;
}
.front:hover + .back {
 opacity: 1;
 visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="front">This is front div</div>
    <div class="back">This is back div</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="front">This is front div</div>
    <div class="back">This is back div</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="front">This is front div</div>
    <div class="back">This is back div</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your problem is, that if the back div shows up, you're no longer hovering over the front div, so it disappears, so you're hovering over the front div again, so the back div reappears - etc ad nauseum. If I were you, I'd go for a `mouseenter` / `mouseleave` approach using JS or JQuery

Comment: @Tijmen I thought JavaScript would be needed too until I saw the answer below

Comment: @Script47 Yes, I hadn't even considered the CSS only solution yet, which is probably better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a div disappear on hover without it flickering when the mouse moves?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844622/how-to-make-a-div-disappear-on-hover-without-it-flickering-when-the-mouse-moves)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It flickers because every time `.back` becomes visible, hover on .front is no longer valid. To solve for this you can set visibility of .back as visible on `.back:hover` which can be done by using the same css style for `.back:hover` as for `.front:hover + .back`

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
}
.row {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
}
.col {
 float: left;
 width: 25%;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
.front {
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
 background-color: #999
}
.back {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 height: 300px;
 opacity: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
 background-color: #ff0;
 z-index: 2;
 width: 100%;
}
.front:hover + .back,
.back:hover {
 opacity: 1;
 visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="front">This is front div</div>
    <div class="back">This is back div</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="front">This is front div</div>
    <div class="back">This is back div</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="front">This is front div</div>
    <div class="back">This is back div</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
}
.row {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
}
.col {
 float: left;
 width: 25%;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
.front {
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
 background-color: #999
}
.back {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 height: 300px;
 opacity: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
 background-color: #ff0;
 z-index: 2;
 width: 100%;
}
.col:hover > .back {
 opacity: 1;
 visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="front">This is front div</div>
    <div class="back">This is back div</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="front">This is front div</div>
    <div class="back">This is back div</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="front">This is front div</div>
    <div class="back">This is back div</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.col:hover > .back {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

I have a simple solution.

Change `.front:hover + .back` => `.col:hover > .back`.

Answer (score 1):

What if you put `.back` element inside `.col` element, move `.front` element styles to `.col` element and add [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition) to `.col` element? I think it's a better solution in view of browsers support.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.row {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.col {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #999
}
.back {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 300px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #ff0;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.col:hover .back {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    This is front part
    <div class="back">This is back part</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    This is front part
    <div class="back">This is back part</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    This is front part
    <div class="back">This is back part</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Bergi but why?

Comment: Because one is the front side of the column and the other is the back side of the column. The back is not a part of the front.

Comment: @Bergi yes, you're right, I've removed `.front` element, now `.back` is part of `.col`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you hover **.front** div the **.back** div appears, so now you're hovering the **.back** div not the **.front** so it disappears again, and the loop continues.
To fix this, add the hover effect to the **.back** div too.
Add `transition` to **.back** for smooth effect.

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
}
.row {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
}
.col {
 float: left;
 width: 25%;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
.front {
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
 background-color: #999
}
.back {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 height: 300px;
 opacity: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
 background-color: #ff0;
 z-index: 2;
 width: 100%;
    transition: 0.2s ease;
}
.front:hover + .back, .back:hover {
 opacity: 1;
 visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="front">This is front div</div>
    <div class="back">This is back div</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="front">This is front div</div>
    <div class="back">This is back div</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="front">This is front div</div>
    <div class="back">This is back div</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you have not been able to tell who really "shoots" the "animation".
Both `front` and `back` are at the same level, so it is not possible to do it from that level, but if you shoot it through the parent element, it should work.

The approach would be as follows:

```
.col:hover .back {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```